# Drag and Drop and Email from Outlook

Tags: c#

I am working on a desktop app in which I want to know if I am able to drag an email from Outlook and drop it onto a control on a form and from them there get the email title and body so that I can display and store it elsewhere in my app.

Im familiar with the drageventargs class but Im not sure if i can use that to do what I want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction if this is at all possible.

Comment: Haven't  you built a prototoype and tried it out to see what happens?

Comment: I have created forms to take the drag and drop but Im not really sure where to start with how to get the drag event to interpret the object that comes from Outlook so there is nothing really to show you on here

Comment: Tip: use your debugger and set a breakpoint on the drop event, and inspect the `EventArgs` when you drop an Outlook email object.

Comment: OK i have done that, it gives me a value of System.Windows.Forms.DataObject in its data property not really sure where i go from there